# Running three.js on chrome mobile

Tags: android, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I have been developing a three.js HTML5 application so far making use of webGL for rendering. The application works fine on the pc but when I tried testing on my mobile which is an Xperia J running Chrome version 28.0.1500.94. I have enabled webGL rendering and webRTC on chrome as well, however all I get is a black screen although Chrome prompts to make use of the webcam. I have also tried to run this [sample](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html) with no luck. My queries are:

1. Can we run webGL rendering on Android with three.js.
2. If so, what are the steps to get it running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you should only need to enable WebGL in chrome flags and make sure you hit the restart button within the flags page.

Just tested Paul Lewes Undulating monkey demo and everything works for me on stable: http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/undulating-monkey/

My suggestion is to check out the developer tools to see what is going on: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: I don't believe we support "experiemnental-webgl" context that android uses.